# Rails: Possible to refactor this query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 active record relation objects with the code as follow:

```
@obj1 = User.select('user.X, table2.Y, table2.Z, count (*)')
            .merge(@some_variable)
            .joins(:table1, :table2)
            .group(1, 2, 3)

@obj2 = User.select('user.X, table2.Y, count (*)')
            .merge(@some_variable)
            .joins(:table1, :table2)
            .group(1, 2)
```

Basically, the only difference between @obj1 and @obj2 is that @obj2 is not selecting table2.Z column data.

Here is a sample data that I would like both @obj to have:

```
@obj1
-------------------------------------
user.X   table2.Y   table2.Z   count
-------------------------------------
 1        1           A         1
 1        1           B         1
 2        1           A         1
 2        1           B         1
 2        1           C         1

@obj2
-------------------------
user.X   table2.Y   count
-------------------------
 1        1          2   
 2        1          3
```

Currently the queries above are working fine, but I believe it is possible to further refactor the code? Like having @obj2 to get the records based on @obj1 data without having to do similar sql query? Appreciate if anyone got input on this. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
columns = %w(users.X, table2.Y table2.Z count(*))
@obj1 = User.merge(@some_variable)
            .joins(:table1, :table2)
            .group(1, 2, 3)
            .select(*columns)
@obj2 = @obj1.select(*(columns - ["table2.Z"]))
```

A further step in refactoring would be to use Arel to replace the string conditions for portability.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't really work. @obj2 does not return anything after executing the code.